# Computing reverse percentile

Tags: statistics, interpolation, percentile

I am actually looking for a way to indicate a certain point on an interpolated curve in a plot (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40662958/3322533)), but judging by the amount of answers there, that's just not possible.

So is there a way to compute the missing coordinate of that point?

More formally:

Given the 1st, 25th, 50th, 75th, 99th and 100th percentile of some data and a value `y`, how do I compute `x` s.t. `y` is the x-th percentile (i.e. s.t. `(x, y)`lies on the curve interpolated from the aforementioned percentiles)?

If not, can I compute it if I have access to the data?

example percentiles:

```
0.01    1.4
0.25    1.4
0.5     1.5
0.75    1.5
0.99    8.9
1   18907.4

mean:   8.0722091348
stdev: 220.0677459302
```

Answer (score 2):

(a) If you just have a few scattered percentiles, then you could do crude
interpolation. (b) If you have sufficient data, you can do a lot better.
(c) If you know the CDF of the population, you can get an exact answer
for the population.

**Suppose you know the distribution** is $X \sim Norm(\mu = 100, \sigma=15)$.
Then the probability that a random observation $X$ lies below 107 can be
found with software or by converting the 'raw score' 107 to the
'standard score' $Z = (107 - 100)/15 = 7/15 = .4667$ and consulting
printed CDF tables of the standard normal distribution. In R statistical
software $P(X \le 107) = P(Z \le 7/15) = 0.6796.$

```
 pnorm(107, 100, 15)  # Norm(100, 15)
 ## 0.6796308
 pnorm(7/15)          # Norm(0, 1), default parameters assumed
 ## 0.6796308
```

If this distribution describes scores on the XYZ College Admissions Test,
and State University is willing to accept students scoring within the top 10%,
then what cutoff point on the XYZ test will they use? The quantile function
is the inverse of the CDF. By using printed normal tables in reverse or
in software you can find the answer. You want $c$ such that $P(X \le c) = .90.$
The answer is that they will probably insist on a score of $c = 120$ or better.

```
qnorm(.9, 100, 15)
## 119.2233
pnorm(119, 100, 15)
## 0.8973627
pnorm(120, 100, 15)
## 0.9087888
```

**Now suppose you have data.** In particular, I have simulated 1000 XYZ 
exam scores (rounded to integers) and put them into the vector `x`. 
I checked, and the sample mean is $\bar X = 100.5$ and the sample
standard deviation is $S = 14.25,$ so this is a fairly typical sample.

What fraction of these
1000 scores lies at or below 107? The answer is 69% (not far from the
theoretical 0.6796 above).
One could sort the 1000 observations from smallest to largest
and count the number at or below 107. (The expression `x <= 107`
is a logical vector of `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s. The `mean` of a logical
vector is its proportion of `TRUE`s.)

```
x = round(rnorm(1000, 100, 15))
## 100.462
## 14.25208
mean(x <= 107)
## 0.69
```

What is a number $c$ below which about 90% of the data lie? Again,
we could get this from a sorted list of the scores? The answer is
119. That is, observation number 900 in the sorted list is 119.

```
quantile(x, .9)
##   90% 
##   119
```

A histogram of the 1000 simulated test scores is shown below. The
vertical lines show values discussed above. The superimposed curve
is the density function of $Norm(100, 15).$ (The fit is about as
good as one should expect for a sample of size 1000.)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how this is helping me ... I just have data and I'm using libreoffice calc to get the percentiles, the mean and the standard deviation. No idea what the distribution is.

Comment: If you have data, then you can find value(s) that match the desired 'percentile'. In my example, 119 is at the 90th percentile (according to R's definition). But for clumpy data like yours, results may not be unique, and various texts and software packages have various ways to give a single value. In your data, value 1.5 seems oft-repeated, so that it is both the 50th percentile (median) and the 75th percentile (upper quartile). Before you start, it is important to have and to understand _one specific_ definition of 'percentile'. (Again, definitions differ; at least 10 are in common use.)